# The karate.sort function throws a TypeError: karate.sort is not a function in <eval> at line number 1 error

Tags: sorting, karate

I'm wring a karate framework test that requires me to assemble a json array and compare it against a response. My assembled array is not in the correct order, to I tried to use the karate.sort() method to rearrange it, but got the error

```
karate.sort is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
```

The version of karate I'm using is **0.9.6** (upgrading to 1.0.1 is a major pita, as our security checks have quarantined some of it's sub-dependencies) and googling the error threw up

I wrote a new test scenario, and copied the sort example from the project, but still got the same error.

```
Scenario: sort
    * def foo = [{a: { b: 3 }}, {a: { b: 1 }}, {a: { b: 2 }}]
    * def fun = function(x){ return x.a.b }
    * def bar = karate.sort(foo, fun)
    * match bar == [{a: { b: 1 }}, {a: { b: 2 }}, {a: { b: 3 }}]
```

the full error message is

```
temp.feature:54 - evaluation (js) failed: karate.sort(foo, fun), javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: karate.sort is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
stack trace: jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:477)
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The `karate.sort()` method is available only on 1.X - so maybe you should write a Java utility to do the sorting if you can't upgrade.